# Submitting html data and staying on same page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form page

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        App Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
        App ID: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php page:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx");
    if (!$con)
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("db", $con);         
    $sql="INSERT INTO app (fname, lname) VALUES('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want it to display `1 record added` on the same page as the form and not have the form send me to a new insert.php page with it. Basically, I want the submit form to stay in the same page with maybe a a new message popping up to show that it has worked.

I have already looked through some answers on stackoverflow like using

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton']))
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe I placed it wrong or used it incorrectly but could someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Search for ajax. You'll get what are you looking for.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton']))` will work, you must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it an action to itself, and set an `if $_POST['submit']` to add the records, and you can have both in the same file. If you wish to do so without refreshing the page, you'll need to use AJAX.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("db", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO app (fname, lname)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con)
}
?>


<form action="" method="post">
App Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
App ID: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, `mysql_*` is **deprecated**, so you should consider converting to PDO or MySQLi to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: This won't work, `$_POST['submit']` should be `$_POST['SubmitButton']`

Comment: I just noticed it, thanks for pointing it out - I edited my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. I get:

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my server. I'm guessing there is a configuration on your server that is different than mine. Try setting `action=""` to the path of this file, so it'll be `action="myform.php"`, of course replace "myform.php" with the actual name.